# How to remove the entire row with values missing only in some columns?

Tags: excel, matlab

I need to remove all rows with empty columns in excel file using matlab programming. I have multiple worksheets inside a single excel file and the data are in a format as follows:

```
1 2 3 4 5
2 3 4 5 
5 6 7 8 9
12 13 14 15 16
6 2 8 4
1 2 3 5 7
9 8 34 3
3 2 7 8 4
```

In the above example, I have empty cells in rows 2, 5, and 7 (all empty cells in column 5). I need to find these empty values and remove rows containing these values i.e. I need to remove only rows 2, 5 and 7. The final output should be like below in an excel file

```
1 2 3 4 5
5 6 7 8 9
12 13 14 15 16
1 2 3 5 7
3 2 7 8 4
```

I looked at some solutions, where rows with all zeros are removed but in this case, I have empty cells only in column 5 but I need to remove the row containing empty values. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using [XLSREAD](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/xlsread.html) to read in your data, it will automatically pad empty cells with [`NaN`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/nan.html) values. You can therefore use the functions [ANY](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/any.html) and [ISNAN](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/isnan.html) to remove the rows containing `NaN` values and save the new data to a file using [XLSWRITE](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/xlswrite.html), like so:

```
data = xlsread('oldfile.xls');
xlswrite('newfile.xls', data(~any(isnan(data), 2), :));
```

Comment: Seems a simple way of dealing the problem. But how to take care of multiple sheets inside the excel file and write a new file?

Comment: @Sham: If you have multiple sheets, you will have to perform the above operation on each one by specifying the additional [`sheet` arguments](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/xlsread.html#inputarg_sheet) for XLSREAD and XLSWRITE to operate on.

Answer (score 1):

Since you data matrix will be of a dimension (8,5) all the empty cells will be 0. So you can do

```
min_data=min(data,[],2); %find the minimum of the rows
data(find(min_data==0),:)=[]; %find the rows of zeros and delete them
```

Comment: Seems a simple way of dealing the problem. But how to take care of multiple sheets inside the excel file and write a new file?

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you can detect and remove rows with empty cells using ActiveX directly:

```
e = actxserver ('Excel.Application'); %# open Activex server
ewb = e.Workbooks.Open('c:\test\test.xlsx'); %# open file (enter full path)
eur = ewb.ActiveSheet.UsedRange; %# lets simplify using active sheet
data = cell2mat(eur.Value); %# get numeric data
idx = find(any(isnan(data),2))'; %# find rows with empty (or text) cells
for k=idx(end:-1:1)
    eur.Rows.Item(k).Delete; %# delete entire row from the last one
end
ewb.Save %# save to the same file
ewb.Close(false)
e.Quit
```

It saves the same altered file so make sure you have a backup while testing!!!

Comment: Thank You man. It seems it will solve my problem but still need time to check on my data. I appreciate it.